# load csv inline clob using pandas to Oracle database

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle

The following code is used to insert a csv file with inline clob column to a Oracle table.

```
rows=tdf.values.tolist()
cursor.execute('select * from job_req_t where rownum <1')
db_types = (ele[1] for ele in cursor.description)
cursor.setinputsizes(*db_types)# to avoid hard coding
cursor.bindarraysize = 200    
insertstmt2='''
INSERT INTO job_req_t (ID,col2,col3,col4lco5,col6,col7 )VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7)
'''
cursor.prepare(insertstmt2)
cursor.executemany(None,rows)
```

Here col2 to col7 are of NCLOB type
While this code works perfectly fine ,It takes an hour to insert a 80 MB file. is there a way to optimize the insert?

Comment: Are there any indexes in `job_req_t`? Rebuilding indexes during `insert` may take ridiculous time. I would suggest deleting the indexes before the insert and adding them back after the insert.

Comment: This is a test table, no it does not have any indexes that I created . But  just noticed that Oracle has created unique index with prefix 'SYS_%' for all the NCLOB columns automatically.